# c# File.Exists gets wrong result when network connection has been lost

Tags: c#, networking, connection, fileinfo

I have to check a file on a mapped network drive.

f.e. P:\myFolder\myFile.dat

```cs
FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(myfile);
if (fi.Exists)
{

    // Exists does not work if the network was interrupted.
    // For whatever reason
    // So now Try ... Catch, the FileInfo constructor can actually be omitted!
    try
    {
        FileVersionInfo fvi = FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(myfile);
        
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException ex)
    {
        this.Version = new Version("1.0.0");
    }
}
else
{
    this.Version = new Version("1.0.0");
}
```

It all works fine - until I unplug my network cable.
The `FileInfo` still thinks the file exists.

Why ?

Comment: Do you perhaps need to call [`FileSystemInfo.Refresh()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filesysteminfo.refresh?view=netcore-3.1) ?

Comment: Could it be that the `FileInfo` object still has its value and was not refreshed? what if you call `File.Exists("path");` in that if statement?

Comment: Or call `Fi.Refresh()` like matthew pointed out.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation states your described behaviour:

> When the properties are first retrieved, FileInfo calls the Refresh method and caches information about the file. On subsequent calls, you must call Refresh to get the latest copy of the information.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.fileinfo

Answer (score 0):

```
fi.Refresh(); worked !
```

@Sommmen
`File.Exists(myfile)` didn't work too.
It had the same problems like the FileInfo